# Joining pandas dataframes with special condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to join these two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["example one", "example word one", "example two", "example sentance one"],
                    "label_1": ["O O", "O W O", "O O", "O S O"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["example one", "example word one", "total example", "example sentance one"],
                    "label_2": ["O N", "O O N", "O O", "O O N"]})


                   text label_1
0           example one     O O
1      example word one   O W O
2           example two     O O
3  example sentance one   O S O

                   text label_2
0           example one     O N
1      example word one   O O N
2         total example     O O
3  example sentance one   O O N
```

My desired output is this:

```
                   text label_1 label_2
0           example one     O O     O N
1      example word one   O W O   O O N
2           example two     O O     NaN
3  example sentance one   O S O   O O N
5         total example     NaN     O O
```

So `text` column should have unique values, and final dataframe should have `label_1` and `label_2` columns with matching values. NaN can be in the result dataframe, but the best thing would be to replace NaN with `O` values that matches the number of words in `text` column (for that row). So if that row has 3 words, NaN should be replaced with `O O O`.

I have tried this, but I haven't got the desired output:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

                   text label_1 label_2
0           example one     O O     NaN
1      example word one   O W O     NaN
2           example two     O O     NaN
3  example sentance one   O S O     NaN
0           example one     NaN     O N
1      example word one     NaN   O O N
2         total example     NaN     O O
3  example sentance one     NaN   O O N
```

Comment: Have you tried [merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) them together? Also see [Pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: `df = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on="text")` The rules for filling `NaN` are little bit more complex

Comment: Ok, thanks for the merging solution, but how to fill nan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on="text")

fill_series = df["text"].str.split().str.len().apply(lambda x: " ".join("0" * x))
fill_cols = ["label_1", "label_2"]
fill_dict = {k: fill_series for k in fill_cols}

df = df.fillna(fill_dict)
```

Outputs:

```
#                    text label_1 label_2
# 0           example one     O O     O N
# 1      example word one   O W O   O O N
# 2           example two     O O     0 0
# 3  example sentance one   O S O   O O N
# 4         total example     0 0     O O
```

`fill_series` creates a `pd.Series` of strings to use for filling.
`fill_cols` are the columns that need filling.
`fill_dict` is the dictionary that applies the strings from the `Series` to the `DataFrame`.